# How do I prevent receive message from FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) being displayed by Android?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote a program that receives message from firebase until program is running, messages are receive by "FirebaseMessagingService" and notification is not generated by Android and the management of the message is not done by the program that I wrote.

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
    }
}
```

But when the program closes, messages are received by "WakefulBroadcastReceiver", But Notification is also created by Android, which displays the received message to the user.

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" }, Categories = new string[] { "XamarinAppFCM.XamarinAppFCM" })]
public class BackgroundBroadcastReciever : Android.Support.V4.Content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var service = new Intent(context, typeof(MyService));

        var title = intent.GetStringExtra("gcm.notification.title");
        var message = intent.GetStringExtra("gcm.notification.body");

        service.PutExtra("title", title);
        service.PutExtra("message", message);

        StartWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}

[Service]
public class MyService : IntentService
{
    public MyService() : base("MyService")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        BackgroundBroadcastReciever.CompleteWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

I want this message not be generated and not seen by the user, and I can manage the display of the message by the program I wrote.
Sometimes the purpose of sending message is to go the program a command to do something like download and upload information. so user not see messages.
please help me.

Comment: In both scenarios whether app is in background or foreground, FirebaseMessagingService's onMessageReceived method needs to be called, android auto handling of FCM messages should not happen, is that what you want?

Comment: yes i dont want android handle automatic.i want even the program is close i can handle message everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of messaging:

1. notification messages
2. data messages

Notification messages are handled by your app when that is active, but they're handled by the system when your app is not active. In contrast: data messages are always handled by your app.

So to ensure it's always your code handling the message, send a data message (without a `notification` property).

Also see the section on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I don't know how sending data messages. please explain more thanks

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Answer (score 0):

Just send data message to prevent firebase client processing FCM message. If fcm message contains notification, firebase client processes it and displays the notification in notification bar.

This is how you need to build just data message in your program that sends FCM message to FCM server for delivery to android client.

```
JsonElement dealsJson = getDealInJsonFormat();

JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
jsonObj.addProperty("topic", "deals");
jsonObj.add("data", dealsJson);

JsonObject msgObj = new JsonObject();
msgObj.add("message", jsonObj);

log.info("json  message "+msgObj.toString());

return msgObj.toString();
```

For complete example, you can check http://www.zoftino.com/android-notification-data-messages-from-app-server-using-firebase-cloud-messaging